# Visualization of view hierarchy on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

Whilst developing iOS apps I found using  `po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]` in the debugger very useful. However, I am wondering whether there is a tool to gracefully represent the output for better readability?

Comment: This looks very fancy: http://revealapp.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use po but I found this tool awhile ago and meant to try it out but haven't.

It embeds itself in your app and exposes itself as a little web app so you can view the state of the view hierarchy while you use the app.

http://blog.thepete.net/blog/2011/05/01/inspect-state-of-our-running-ios-apps/

EDIT:

Adding [sparkinpector](http://www.sparkinspector.com/) which was mentioned in the comments.  I checked it out and it seems very cool - especially if you create views programmatically.

Comment: that looks very promising.  Thanks

Comment: You might also want to check out DCIntrospect (https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCIntrospect) and the Spark Inspector (http://www.sparkinspector.com). They're newer and don't require Frankifying your app. (Full disclosure - I'm the author of the Spark Inspector!)

Answer (score 2):

here is a method I wrote back in the days:

```
- (void)logView:(UIView*)v index:(int)i
{
    NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString string];
    for (int u = 0; u<i; u++) { [str appendString:@"| "]; }
    [str appendFormat:@"<%@ %p frame:%@>", v.class, v, NSStringFromCGRect(v.frame)];
    // of course you can change it to display your accessibility hint/label
    printf("%s\n", [str UTF8String]);

    for (UIView *vv in v.subviews) { [self logView:vv index:i+1]; }
}
```

call it like so: `[self logView:myView index:0];`

sample output:

```
<UITextField 0x6b30010 frame:{{20, 13}, {280, 31}}>
| <UITextFieldRoundedRectBackgroundView 0x6b31e00 frame:{{0, 0}, {280, 31}}>
| | <UIImageView 0x6b31fe0 frame:{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}>
| | <UIImageView 0x6b32070 frame:{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}>
| | <UIImageView 0x6b320e0 frame:{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}>
```

Comment: thanks for sharing this. It actually looks quite like the recursiveDescription output, right ?

Comment: its shorter than that. eg. many objects have more description values like title and font, type etc. But you can adjust the formatting via the `appendFormat:` method `<%@ %p frame:%@>`

Answer (score 0):

There definitely are. We've come a long way in the last few years, and `-recursiveDescription` is a pretty painful way to see your view hierarchy - especially when your interface is complex. Take a look at this answer for some newer solutions:

[I need to inspect the view hierarchy on an iPhone program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343246/i-need-to-inspect-the-view-hierarchy-on-an-iphone-program/16886402#16886402)

Answer (score 0):

Use reveal app: http://revealapp.com.

This might help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one private way,

write following code,

```
NSLog("%@",[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] performSelector(@selector(recursiveDescription))]);
```

similarly for any view:

```
NSLog("%@",[view performSelector(@selector(recursiveDescription))]);
```

this will give you the whole view hierarchy.

Please make note that, dont submit your code to apple after using this method in your application, because this is private api. Just, use these for only debugging purpose.