# iOS6 Search Bar Placeholder text is off center and can't select

Tags: ios, ipad, uisearchbar

In iOS6 the Search Bar Placeholder text is off center and can't select it.

I have tried popover and modal.

Anyone seen this before and know how to correct?

[image]

EDIT:
I think it has to do with I created this project in XCode5 and running it in XCode4x.  It has to do with the status bar pushing things down.  Anyone know how to correct this?

Comment: If you enter some text is it on the right position, or off center too?

Comment: I am not able to enter text, I click and keyboard does not show.

Comment: Try setting UISearchBar.searchTextPositionAdjustment in order to lift up search bar's text view

Comment: I tried to set the searchTextPositionAdjustment and had no effect on the position or able to edit.

Comment: I guess there is something wrong with it UIView hierarchy then. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343246/i-need-to-inspect-the-view-hierarchy-on-an-iphone-program for some ways to display it. I don't have other ideas.

Comment: This was the output...looks ok to me...UITableView
{{0, 0}, {320, 619}}
    UISearchBar
    {{0, 0}, {320, 44}}
        UISearchBarBackground
        {{0, 0}, {1024, 44}}
        UISearchBarTextField
        {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
        UIImageView
        {{0, 0}, {1, 1}}

Comment: It's not ok. UISearchBarTextField {{0, 0}, {0, 0}} means you don't actually have a text field to tap on! The background is too wide which though not a problem in this case, speaks of something wrong with the setup. Better compare your setup with other setups if similar software.