# iOS: Can a view place another subview on its superview?

Tags: ios, subview, superview

I have a `UIScrollView` with a custom view called `LVSBBView`. `LVSBBView` has subviews that are of custom type `LVSBBNode`. These nodes are created recursively (like a tree) and I'd like to be able to create a new "child" node within `LVSBBNode` and then make it a subview of `LVSBBView`. This doesn't seem to be working -- the new views never show up. If I create all the views within `LVSBBView`'s controller, it works OK.

The code I'm using to create the "child" node within `LVSBBNode` is:

```
LVSBBNode *child = [[LVSBBNode alloc] init];
// ...set properties of child here...
[self.superview addSubview:child];
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Seems like it should work. Is `self.superview` `nil` when you call `addSubview:`? Are you also sure that the new child node is placed properly visually?

Comment: You can also split out the `recursiveDescription` on any `UIView` to the log, this will tell you if in-fact your child node is being added to the view hierarchy : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343246/i-need-to-inspect-the-view-hierarchy-on-an-iphone-program

Comment: @Aaron: Turns out `self.superview` **was** `nil`. I was creating the child nodes before adding the root node as a subview. Oops! Thanks for the suggestion. (Also, `recursiveDescription` is a nice trick -- thanks for that too.)

Comment: Sure, I'll re-add all that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it should work. I bet `self.superview` is `nil` when you call `-addSubview:`

You can also split out the `-recursiveDescription` on any `UIView` to the log. This will tell you if in-fact your child node is being added to the view hierarchy: [I need to inspect the view hierarchy on an iPhone program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343246/i-need-to-inspect-the-view-hierarchy-on-an-iphone-program)